# Is there a way to invoke my java code (jar, class) from liquibase changelog?

Tags: java, liquibase

I need to execute enough complex logic of data manipulation at time of database restructuring by [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/). More precisely speaking it's need to do between two acts of data model changes. The data manipulation logic is performed in external java code. There is no way to move one in SQL.

Is there a way to invoke the external java code (jar, class) from liquibase changelog?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it to use a `<customChange>` tag referencing a class that implements liquibase.change.custom.CustomSqlChange or liquibase.change.custom.CustomTaskChange

example:

```
    <customChange class="com.example.YourClass">
        <param name="tableName" value="table"/>
        <param name="columnName">column</param>
    </customChange>
```

You can implement whatever java code you want in your class.